# Use Environment Variables from a container

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker

I have a pod deployed with environmental variables defined. I have a variable, VERSION, that I would like to display on my sidebar of my app. I’m very new to react and typescript, so what I tried was process.env.VERSION, but no luck. How can I retrieve that environment variable

```
export const AppSidebar = () => {
    const classes = useSidebarLogoStyles();
    // Use the locator pattern (GoF Patterns) to lookup identityAPI by a reference (object)
    // const object = locator.lookup("identityRef")
    const identityApi = useApi(identityApiRef);
    return (
        <Sidebar>
          <SidebarLogo />
          <div className={classes.upperversion}> v1.2.3 </div>
          <div className={classes.firstbar}>
            <SidebarDivider/>
            ...
          <div className={classes.buttomstyle}> {process.env.VERSION} </div>
        </Sidebar>
    );
```

Comment: The React code presumably isn't actually running in the container, it's running in the users' browsers. It _can't_ access the env vars directly. How you might be able to expose them depends on what's running in the container.

Comment: Is there a workaround you might suggest?

Comment: I was wondering if I could add a .env file and send that to that file. Would I be able to grab that from that file? `echo VERSION=$APP_VERSION" >> .env`

Comment: Typically your .env file is explicitly excluded from git, let alone the build directory. It's also not an abstraction that really makes sense for client side code, I would (and do, in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html) suggest thinking JS, JSON or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `create-react-app` tool for building/serving your app. In that case you can have access to env variables, but only if those are prefixed with `REACT_APP_`.
For example `REACT_APP_VERSION`.

Then in the code you should be able to access it like `process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION`.

Comment: For reference https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: No non of them start with REACT_APP_

Comment: @MaxBojorquez, I know, but I assume you have control over container and its env variables, so just rename it if you can.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov I changed the variable name, but not displaying. Not sure if I have the syntax write. `<div className={classes.upperversion}> {process.env.REACT_APP_DP_VERSION} </div>`

Comment: @MaxBojorquez you need to run build in that container, so env variables are fetched during the build. Those cannot be included during run time.